# Correct syntaxis for event tracking in Google Analytics 2015

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, analytics.js

im new at implementing event tracking in analytics, this is a contact form and i would like to know if my syntaxis is correct, google analytics help is not very none code savvy friendly i think. I'm using the jQuery example they provide.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl-contacto">Escríbenos</button>
<script>
$('#btn btn-xl-contacto').on('click', function() {
ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'boton-contacto');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct.

When in doubt, you can always just try it to see if it's working. Using the [analytics_debug.js script](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#debug) works great for that. It allows you to look at the web console and see exactly what's happening.

Comment: Thanks Philip, any tips about how to use debug? mostly i'm worried that even though hiting submit on that button it does register as a conversion in my GA Conversion dashboard.

Comment: No tips other than what's on that page I linked to.

Comment: this is the site i'm working on: [link](http://amymstudio.com/clientes/integrandoequipos/)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

i was using and id instead of a class when calling for the script:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl-contacto">Escríbenos</button>
<script>
$('.btn-xl-contacto').on('click', function() {
ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'boton-contacto');
});
</script>
```

changed the '#' for a '.' and used just the last class atribute (in this case btn-xl-contacto).

Everything works fine now.